# How to set up Application Insights Transaction Diagnostics?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have set up Application Insights as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net). I have enabled transaction diagnostics as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-transaction-diagnostics). I am able track dependency calls, requests, page views and all telemetry I want see. The issue is that I am not able to see remote HTTP calls in end-to-end transaction details when I select any Request telemetry. My application is internally calling Azure Key Vault APIs, I want these to be part of transaction details.

Comment: Have you upgrade to latest nuget packages from Application Insights? You need to be at least on 2.4 for correlation to work properly.

Comment: Yes, I have installed latest nuget packages. But my application is on .Net 4.5.2. Does it matter?

Comment: .Net 4.5.2 should work. Do you track everything manually? Or is everything captured automatically but doesn't show up in end-to-end transactions details?

Comment: I am not tracking anything manually. I have set up as described in the article mentioned in the question.

Comment: So, AI SDK captures both requests and HTTP calls to Key Vault as a part of them, you see them in Analytics and in UX. But you don't see these outgoing HTTP calls as a part of requests, correct?

Comment: @ZakiMa that is correct. I want to see them as part of transaction.

Comment: Can you paste dependency (HTTP call to Key Vault) and request as a part of it this was made? (in Analytics portal). Also, can you please paste ApplicationInsights.config and packages.config?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was quite simple. I had to update my application to .Net version 4.6.1. Now I have my dependencies linked to Request telemetry.

Comment: thank you for finding a solution. It looks like either some new issue or something else happened at the same time. If you could file an issue on github (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server) and provide a small repro or examples of documents before and after upgrade - would help us to fix the issue or detect it and recommend a fix in UX!

Comment: We tried some simple key-vault scenario and everything worked on .NET 4.5.2. Will appreciate more info/repro =)